# Convert date to M-d-y format in PHP

Tags: php, backbone.js, laravel-5

How do I change the date format using PHP?  I have used the following code but it is displaying the date input field value as m-d-Y. Why it is changing the format?

```
  $effectivedate = date('M-d-Y', strtotime($empCompensationdata-effective_date));
 $effective_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($empCompensationdata-effective_date));
 $("#effective_date").val($effectivedate);
 $('#effective_date').attr('data-value', $effective_date);
```

Comment: can you please show us your O/P ?

Comment: Please include value of $empCompensationdata->effective_date

Comment: O/P: 06-08-2015  ,But i want to this format Jun-08-2015  please check once..

Comment: Yes i included  $empCompensationdata->effective_date;  and also i checked that date in console ie correct formate link (Jun-08-2015)  , but appearing date in input field is showing this format 06-08-2015.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the value is displayed as M-d-Y is because that's what you're assigning to it with the val() method:

```
$effectivedate = date('M-d-Y', strtotime($empCompensationdata->effective_date));
 $effective_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($empCompensationdata->effective_date));
 $("#effective_date").val($effectivedate); //This variable contains "M-d-Y"
 $('#effective_date').attr('data-value', $effective_date);
```

So if you want to have Y-m-d, just change the assigning variable:

```
$("#effective_date").val($effective_date); //This variable contains "Y-m-d"
```